# Using generic functions in enums

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I am trying to use enums to contain generic functions. These enums will be passed as arguments, where the functions in the enums can then be executed accordingly.

How would you set the generic type in the enum definition such that they will be recognized as functions to be executed? Note that I might have various function definitions that i might want to pass in.

Let me know if i am being ridiculous here. :)

---

```
// Define an enum to pass into my APIs. The S and F are meant to be functions I can define in anyway
enum FormattedResult<S, F> {
    case Success(S)
    case Failure(F)

    func run<T> (a:T) {
        switch (self){
        case .Success (let completion):
            // QN: How do I execute this? completion() will of course fail
            debugPrint(completion)
        case .Failure (let failure):
            // QN: Same here
            debugPrint(failure)
        }
    }
}


// I want to define a callback for someone else to call. I will be passing this to the error
var k1 = FormattedResult<(Int)-> (), (String)->() >.Success(
    {(a: Int) in
        debugPrint("xxxxx")
    })

// the APIClient can run this upon completion
k1.run(2)

// similarly for failures
var k2 = FormattedResult<(Int)-> () , (String)->()>.Failure(
    {(error: String)  in
        debugPrint(error)
    }
    )
k2.run("some error happened...")
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `T` in the `run<T> (a: T)` method?

Comment: so the caller can pass in a value to be executed y by the run function.

Comment: the run funcition is supposed to take the function defined by "success" and run it with T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original codes, although define a closure as a callback when creating a variable `k1` or `k2`, `S` and `F` are still just placeholder types and doesn’t say anything about what `S` & `F` must be. Therefore, the challenge here is how to define Swift enumerations to store associated values of a given function type.

So the idea is we can use a function type such as `(T) -> void` as a parameter type for enum and leaving some aspects of a function’s implementation for alongside enum case values to provide when the function of enum is called.

The next thing is we don’t need two placeholder types in the enum since we only have one type of `a` each time the function `run(:)` is called even though it could be `String` or `Int`. It’s also the power of what `Generic` to be. Although the placeholder type `T` doesn’t say anything about what `T` must be, but it does say that both `a` and associated values of enum `(T) -> void` must be of the same type T, whatever T represents. Therefore, one type placeholder is enough in this case.

Actually, I like your idea that the caller can pass in a value to be executed by the run function in enums and you are almost there in your original codes. The following is an example of what I mentioned above.

```
enum FormattedResult<T> {
    case Success(((T) -> Void))
    case Failure(((T) -> Void))

    func run(a:T) {
        switch self {
        case Success(let completion):
            completion(a)
        case Failure(let completion):
            completion(a)
        }
    }
}

let f1 = FormattedResult.Success({ a in
    debugPrint(a)
})
f1.run(1)

let f2 = FormattedResult.Failure({ error in
    debugPrint(error)
})
f2.run("some error happened...")
```

Comment: thanks a lot! glad you see the point. trying out your solution now. :)

Comment: this is what i ended up with, what do you think? https://gist.github.com/mingyeow/ef740dd3d70455a84c01

Comment: @mingyeow I like it. As to the struct ``FailureReason``, I might have it implement with the protocol ``CustomStringConvertible`` <pre><code>struct FailureReason: CustomStringConvertible {
    var code:Int!
    var message:String!
    
    var description: String {
        return "Error code \(code): \(message)"
    }
}</code></pre>

Comment: Done! Thanks Allen. Btw, can you point out what is the main error in my code? Yours is much simpler but works really well

Comment: @mingyeow I just revised my answer little bit. Please take it for references. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't treat `completion` or `failure` as a closure because you don't know what type they are.

If you use `S` and `F` to provide the type that the caller needs to pass in, then you're able to specify the associated type of your Success and Failure values.

```
enum FormattedResult<SuccessArg, FailArg> {
    case Success(SuccessArg -> Void)
    case Failure(FailArg -> Void)
}
```

Note: If you wanted to define a non-void return value then you'll have to add two more generic parameters and replace `Void`.

Next problem: implementing the run function.

```
extension FormattedResult {
    func run(a:AnyObject) {
        switch (self){
        case .Success (let completion):
            // completion is of type (SuccessArg -> Void)
            if let successArg = a as? SuccessArg {
                completion(successArg)
            } else {
                fatalError() //??
            }
        case .Failure (let failure):
            // failure is of type (FailArg -> Void)
            if let failArg = a as? FailArg {
                failure(failArg)
            } else {
                fatalError() //??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am admittedly confused about what the run function. Shouldn't the caller of `run` know whether it was a `Success` or `Failure`? Because the clients of your API are choose to either implement the SuccessCase or FailureCase; the caller must provide values for both success and failure.

I might have misunderstood and this is what you're looking for:

```
extension FormattedResult {
    func run(a:SuccessArg, b:FailArg) {
        switch (self){
        case .Success (let completion):
            // completion is of type (SuccessArg -> Void)
            completion(a)
        case .Failure (let failure):
            // failure is of type (FailArg -> Void)
            failure(b)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what i am looking for. i understand the confusion, i am figuring it out myself as to whether i am taking generics too far. will implement and get back to you

Comment: I don't think you're taking generics too far at all, but you might be misusing enums. I would think users want to handle both the Success case and the Failure case.

Comment: the thing is, the user of run will want to run both success and failure. for example, i am passing my apiclient a formattedResult enum with both success/failure functions defined.  when the result succeeds or fails, they will execute them using run(). Make sense?

Comment: this is what i ended up with: https://gist.github.com/mingyeow/ef740dd3d70455a84c01